# How to access methods of classes stored in an unordered_map in C++

Tags: c++, class, unordered-map

So I have a class named Account and I am storing it in an unordered_map, but when I try to access the functions of that class within the map, it fails to compile.  The class is stored in a header file "Bank.h"

```
class Account {
    double balance;
    std::string username;

    public:
    Account(double balance, std::string username);

    double getBal() {
        return this->balance;
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return this->username;
    }

    void updateBal(double amount) {
        this->balance += amount;
    }
};
```

These functions are stored in a separate cpp file with #include "Bank.h"

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Account> accountList;
Account test(100, "Tester");
std::cout << test.getBal();
accountList.insert(std::make_pair("Test", test));
accountList["Test"].getName();
```

Comment: Should you try to use 'accountList.at("Test").getName();'?

Answer (score 1):

```
accountList["Test"].getName();
```

The `[]` operator on an unordered map (and `std::map` too) has a mandatory requirement that must be met: if the map's key does not exist, it gets created and the corresponding value gets default-constructed.

Unfortunately, your `Account` class does not have a default constructor, hence the compilation failure.

It is true that just before this line of code you are inserting a value for `"Test"` into the map, so it'll exist. This, unfortunately, does not matter. All requirements of the `operator[]` must be met, including the map's value requirement to have a default constructor.

You have two options to resolve your compilation error:

1. Add a default constructor to your `Account` class, or
2. You cannot use `[]`, instead use `at()`; or use `find()` (and compare its result to `end`()).

Comment: I think that in addition to that, you have to also create a hash function for `std::string`, am I right?

Comment: It is true that the unordered map's key must have a hash function. The good news is that one already exists in the C++ library and nothing more needs to be done about it.